# How to assign TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton to a TextBox's Text in code behind (MahApps)

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

This is how i am do this using `XAML`:

```
<TextBox Name="tb"
         Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" />
```

Any way to do that in code behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with the following line of C# code in your code behind:

```
MyTextBox.SetValue(MahApps.Metro.Controls.TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButtonProperty, true);
```

Just tested and verified =)